# Why is induced EMF of an inductor considered as average voltage and not RMS or maximum?

Tags: voltage, inductor, maximum-ratings, rms, single-phase

So my professor discussed to us about induced EMF of an inductor and mentioned that it is an average value and not maximum or RMS if you were to consider which type of voltage it is from the different types of AC voltages. I want to ask, why is this so? It really gets confusing since usually in textbooks they use the small letter e, and I associate that with the maximum value in time domain equations of instantaneous voltage, \$ e = E_msin(wt + θ) \$.

Another additional question is that, should you never assume the category of a quantity based on associated notations? Like for example, although the small e is commonly used for induced EMF you have to know that it is an average value through studying because most textbooks won't use a notation such as \$ E_{ave} \$ just to point that out.

Comment: "*in textbooks they use the small letter e, and I associate that with the maximum value in time domain equations of instantaneous voltage, e=Emsin(wt+θ).*" Did you mean to say what you actually wrote? Because you say you interpret little e is the peak amplitude but then say that is e = some equation. Normal convention (though not always adhered to) is that upper case represents a DC value or peak amplitude, while lower case represents a time varying value or instantaneous value.

Comment: Your question seems very unclear. As long as you know what RMS and peak and whatnot mean, you can use them whenever appropriate. I suppose there could be problems if you read an equation and they use a single letter for a voltage and you are not sure whether it is the RMS value or peak-to-peak or what. When it matters, it should always be specified or known by clear convention.

Comment: I meant that I associated the small e with the time domain equations, not take e literally as a maximum voltage which is why I got the confusion with maximum voltage. My issue really is intuitively associating the induced EMF with average voltage, because why is it average and not the others? By the way I've read the other answers here, and I'm waiting if there will be more.

Comment: It's an instantaneous voltage. If he's calling it an average there must be some context to that statement that didn't make it into the question. I recommend asking him at the next tutorial session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really think about what RMS physically means for inductors and capacitors, it doesn't make a lot of physical sense. RMS was intended for representing the equivalent DC heating in resistors. Average and peak values tends to make a lot more physical sense for inductors or capacitors.

That said, when you do the math you have to keep things consistent; You can't just mix up RMS, average, and peaks.

But your professor must have been speaking about some specific context that you left out or did not notice. For example, if you are concerned about the current in an inductor in a switching converter, where the current ripples above and below a mid-point (rather than weaving above and below 0A), you probably want to work with the average.

If you want to figure out how much charge has been stored in a cap at the end of a cycle, you would work with the instantaneous voltage at the end of the cycle (which would also be the peak voltage if the current was going in one direction into the capacitor the entire cycle so that the voltage only ever climbed) since that voltage represents the history of charge in the capacitor.

Then for that capacitor, if you wanted to find out the equivalent current that would produce that voltage if it were constant, you would use the average current.

You can see from these examples it is all based on context. When in doubt, especially for complex waveforms, you should use instantaneous values. This could be the equation describing the waveform, or actual data points if it is an arbitrary signals measured in the real world. This is what nature does. Nature doesn't know the RMS, the average, or the peak. It doesn't know the equation of the waveform. It just knows the moment-to-moment values. But it is cumbersome do it this way since it involves working with an equation or hundreds if not thousands of data points.

That is the reason we have things like RMS, average, and peak. They are just all abstractions that boil down all those datapoints into a handful of numbers that we humans can use on paper-napkin calculations. But since they are boiled down, they make assumptions and do not capture the entire behaviour of the waveform. They have their limitations and do NOT apply in all cases so you just have to know what you are working with.

Another example of such an abstraction is reactive power and apparent power. In reality, it is all real power. Just that if you have X amount of real power flowing from source to load, and then X amount of real power at some later time flowing back from load to source, it is accounted for as reactive power. But working with it this way requires working with the power waveform as it goes above and below zero (representing changes in direction of power flow) and is difficult to handle without a computer.

If you want a specific answer to what your prof said, please provide us with the context about what was being discussed as the time.

---

Generally, but not always, upper case notation defines a DC value, DC-bias or a peak amplitude while lowercase represents an AC value (to be superimposed on top of a DC-bias) or instantaneous value (such as that from an equation describing the waveform.

Comment: Well, in steady state AC analysis, the average current in an inductor is typically zero. And the average voltage across a capacitor is typically zero. I don't know if I am just slow or what but I don't really understand the OP's question at all. It is very important to know what all these terms mean (RMS, peak, peak-to-peak, amplitude, etc) but I don't feel that there is all that much confusion about it most of the time.

Comment: @mkeith I guess I was thinking more of SMPS when I posted my answer rather than an AC mains circuit.

Comment: If the problem is a lack of understanding of definitions, then someone could probably restate or elaborate them for me to make it clear why which types work and do not work for certain situations. For example, why average for induced EMF and why everything else wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @AndroidV11 Do you have a scenario you can present us with? What *exactly* was your prof talking about when he said his thing? Because forcing a sinusoidal current through an inductor will cause a cosine voltage across the inductor. In which case RMS or peak might be useful for numerical consistency in the math when calculating. But if you're forcing a linear current ramp through the inductor then you have a constant voltage across the inductor and an "average" (or more accurately, an instantaneous value that never changes) might make more sense.

Comment: When in doubt, work with instantaneous values (though often numerical cumbersome unless you can describe the waveform as a function) since that is what nature does. RMS, peak, average, and all that junk are numerical abstractions humans use to try and boil down the infinite number of instantaneous values in a waveform down to a handful of values so we can do paper napkin calculations (and aren't always valid, especially for arbitrary waveforms). Nature doesn't look at what the average value or RMS value is of something to decide what to do. It only looks at the moment-to-moment values.

Comment: Every abstraction you make (RMS, average, peak, whatever) has to make sense when you look at it in terms of the instantaneous moment-to-moment values. Simplest example is using average voltage to calculate power for sine-waves. it universally averages to zero but if you look at the moment-to-moment values which reign supreme they definitely do not average to zero except in very specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

A voltage can be *measured* in many ways, as a peak, an rms, an average. The question is in any given circumstance, which way of measuring the voltage gives us the most useful information?

If we want to know when insulation breaks down, then we use the peak.

If we want to know about heating into a constant resistor, then rms is best, it's based on an average of V<sup>2</sup>.

If an inductor has a certain current flowing which is then interrupted, the voltage will be generated according to \$V = L\frac{dI}{dt}\$. The integral form is \$ IL = \int{V}{dt} \$  which shows the current is proportional to a time average of V.

Therefore if we use the average of the voltage, we get something proportional to the inductor current. The peak or the rms would not have this property.

There are too many versions of too many quantities to give them all their own letter, which then stays consistent across all the physical sciences. Sometimes the type is clear from the context, sometimes you have to go to the glossary to see how the author is using his particular notation.

Comment: IWhy is the average of the voltage proportional to the inductor current? Is it because integral is considered as average? I never understood this. Yes, I know their derivative and integral forms but it never really stuck with me why they are referred to as average. I'm not used to such intuition. What I do get is that you compute an exact area with the integral but I don't get why it is average.
I get that how you explained it makes sense, but I just really want to get an intuitive grasp and not just "Oh its integral/EMF equation" that's why it's average which I can't seem to get.

Comment: To the OP: "Average" is another word for "mean." The mean of a function over some interval is just the area divided by the length of the interval. So I suppose that is why the average and integral are related. Not sure if that helps you.

Comment: @AndroidV11 In less mathy terms, the average value is the unchanging value you would need to have in order to accumulate the same amount of "stuff" at the very end of the time period as the actual thing (which is not an unchanging value). An integral is the mathy way of saying accumulation.

Comment: The average most people know is adding up everything and dividing by the number of things. So average of 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 is (2+4+6+8+10)/5. That addition part is integration when you have a discrete number of things or points. But not all things are discrete. Many are continuous, like waveforms.